# Uxie and Azelf Are Not Appearing in Nameless Cavern

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

Every time since a few days ago after I caught Mespirit, when I go to the portal in the Nameless Cavern and I press A to interact. All that happens is a short dialog sequence and nothing else. I know the requirements are along the lines of having 3 max happiness Pokemon with you in your party which I do. I have also downloaded the recent update/patch from the eShop if that helps at all. How can I make Uxie and Azelf appear in the cavern?

Comment: not putting down an answer because i'm not certain but beating the pokemon league often resets legendary encounters in this series

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually it does indeed depend on the time set on your 3DS and having 3 max happiness pokes in your party. Uxie can only be caught between 20:00 and 21:00 hours. so between 8pm-9pm. Azelf can be caught between 21:00 and 03:59 or 9PM and 3:59AM and then mesprit the rest of the time. all the info is right here on this page on Serebii

http://www.serebii.net/omegarubyalphasapphire/legendary.shtml

I've confirmed from personal experience. everything on this page is true to the letter. have fun!

Comment: Didn't know they were all explained on Serebii, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

They appear at different times. Uxie is from 8pm until 9pm, Azelf is from 9pm until 3:59am, and Mesprit you can find from 4am until 7:59pm. However, they will not appear if you have changed DS's or times and like with all legendaries within the game will not show up for 24 hours.

Comment: This was my problem - I recently realised my 3DS's AM/PM was reversed and decided I may as well set it to 8pm so that Uxie would show up but it didn't

Answer (score 1):

I've found [this thread](http://pokemondb.net/pokebase/222325/can-someone-tell-how-the-lake-trio-aka-uxie-mesprit-azelf-oras), and there's an answer you may find useful.

> You need the Eon Flute from Southern Island. Lati@s doesn't need to be
> in your party, just in your possession. Soar to Sootopolis and soar
> around until you find the red sparkle called "Nameless Cavern (I
> believe)". Land there and enter in. The Hoopa ring should be in there.
>
> You need 3 max happiness Pokemon (I had a whole party of
> max happiness Pokemon when I caught Mesprit). I believe they are at
> certain times of day.

Hope this can help you, I haven't caught them yet so I don't know if this actually works.

Comment: The only somewhat helpful (if true) thing here is that you need 3 max happiness Pokemon with you. However, I have been going to Nameless Cavern many times with a full party of max happiness Pokemon, and I keep getting the same one.

Comment: @Chippies You DO need 3 max happiness Pokemon, and it's true that they appear at certain times of the day, too. See *Satondai* answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, you must have at least three pokemon in you party with max happiness or friendship. I am unsure which. Second, you must find Nameless Cavern. It's a Mirage Spot southwest of mossdeep and northeast of sootopolis. Third, each will appear at a certain time, Mesprit is there from  4 am to 8 pm, Uxie is from 8 pm to 9 pm, and Azelf from 9 pm to 4 am. DO NOT TIME CHEAT! They will not spawn if you time cheat! I know from experience! The only way to get them to respawn if you time cheat is to beat the Elite 4, but I haven't tested this yet, I am going to tommorrow and post results.

Answer (score -1):

You need 3 pokemon with max happiness and I think that V1.2 screwed somthing up, because I have Ho-oh however I can't get Entei, Raikou, Suicune but I could get Mesprit before the patch.
So if you can't find it, I would just go after some other Legendaries. (Note: you need Ho-oh or Lugia and one other legendary in your party to encounter Entei, Raikou and Suicune)