# Why can't I catch Uxie or Azelf even though I have the requirments?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I tried to catch Uxie, Azelf and Mesprit, but could only catch Mesprit. I know that they appear at different times, but it is 8:07 pm for me and Uxie does not appear.

My 3DS time is at 20:01 (I'll change it soon) and Uxie still doesn't appear. I decided to leave Nameless Cavern and land there again, but it didn't show up. I have 3 Pokémon with max happiness. Why can't I catch Uxie or Azelf?

Comment: Do the answers here help? - [Uxie and Azelf Are Not Appearing in Nameless Cavern](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/194715/uxie-and-azelf-are-not-appearing-in-nameless-cavern)

Comment: If you changed your ds clock then you will have to wait 24 hours before they will reappear.