# Having trouble catching Uxie in Omega Ruby/Alpha Sapphire

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I am trying to catch the legendary lake guardians, and have already caught Axelf and Mesprit.

I enter Nameless Cavern at exactly 20:00, but nothing happens. I look over the portal, but all it says is *"A mysterious ring is floating in the air..."*.

How do I catch Uxie?

Comment: It's actually about Pokemon I'm new to it but whatever

Answer (score -1):

Isn't this question a duplicate of this question:

[Uxie and Azelf Are Not Appearing in Nameless Cavern](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/194715/uxie-and-azelf-are-not-appearing-in-nameless-cavern)

check your ds time and enter at ~8:30 PM. If there are any minor irregularities this will correct them. Also you need 3 max happiness pokemon on your team.

Comment: If a question is a duplicate, flag it, don't answer it.

Comment: 1) I answered it 2) I saw other questions 3) I realised it was a duplicate. Also this is convenient to people coming here as they have to click one less link